Why is overflow scrolling not working on big screen?
I am working on a Vue project and I have this HTML:
 <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
  <div class="m-6 ml-10 mr-5 mt-10">
    <div class="text-left">
      <input type="text" class="mb-6 h-10 w-full rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-300 p-2" placeholder="Search for workouts, profiles, etc." />
    </div>
    <div class=" ">
      <div class="mb-3 text-left">
        <p>Explore workouts</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex h-28 flex-row gap-3 overflow-x-auto whitespace-nowrap">
        <div class="box inline-flex min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
        <div class="box inline-block min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
        <div class="box min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
        <div class="box min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
        <div class="box min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
        <div class="box min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
        <div class="box mb-5 min-w-52 bg-black"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

I am using tailwind for this. The problem is that I have overflow-x-auto does not work on big screen sizes but when I minimize the screen it works. On big screen it scrolls into a white space. Will add a photo underneath with how it looks like on big screen vs small screen.
I tried to use positioning relative but that did not work.
On big screen:

on small screen:


Hi @CS student, your issue isn't really clear. I just tried to replicate your code and it seems to me that the cards do not overflow into a white space on large screens. If that's not the case, can you create a codesandbox with your code for better understanding. It is also important to see the structure of the html file.

Hello, @praizjosh
I found out that what's causing the issue. I have a div that wraps the whole layout. And for that im using bulma css classnames "column p-0 is-flex-tablet is-flex-direction-row". When removing the classes the overflow classname would work. so it seems like flex interfere with overflow

Good to know you figured it out. Cheers!

yeah, I figured out what's causing the issue, but not really how to fix it. I can't remove the flex from the first div. Because thats how I define the layout with the navbar. @praizjosh

The solution is to add a width to the second div that wraps the whole content. I added a width of 80% and that solved the issue

Replace your div:
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">

with this:
<div class="flex flex-col">

it seems to be working as expected now. https://play.tailwindcss.com

Hi, i have flex-row because I want the navbar to be on the left side of the content (it's not shown on the code snippet I added to my question). If I remove flex-row the navbar will be on top of the content (but I only want that to happen on the screen is small)
